Service Worker has error when is installed
I'm programming a Service Worker for Windows Server using Visual Studio 2022. Upon installation, the following error arises:
"Windows cannot start the xxxxx service on the local computer.
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely manner."
Upon checking the Windows Event Viewer, I encountered this error:
"User 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' login failure. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'Bunker'. [CLIENT: ]"
During debugging in VS 2022, there are no connection errors; they only occur upon installation.
I've already verified the user and their permissions in the SQL Server database. Additionally, I attempted to reinstall the service worker.
I'd appreciate some assistance in resolving this issue.
Here is the code snippet for the database connection.


The service, once installed, is in its own execution context and can be started even before a user is authenticated.
It looks like your application uses a connectionstring using Windows authentication

@MehdiKacim
the service utilizes EF Core, and the Context indeed contains a connection string, but it employs SQL Server authentication.

Are you sure?  The error message is quite clear that the database connection is attempting to be made as the user running the service (NT Authority\System or LocalSystem is the default user for a Window's service).  Maybe update your question with your connection string (mask any sensitive passwords, of course).

@Mark Yes, I'm sure. The service worker functions properly when debugged in VS 2022, but when installed on Windows, this problem occurs. The connection string is assembled at runtime, performing SQL Server authentication.
I'll edit the question and include the code snippet where the connection string is created.

Your connection string specifies Integrated Security=True, this will use the windows user.   See documentation here.

@Mark I deleted this, and the service worked. Thank you very much.

You have to choose between Windows Authentication or SQL Server authentication. You are attempting to use both, and it appears that Windows Authentication is chosen. The error occurs since the user that the service is running under does not have a valid Login with that instance.
To use Windows Authentication, make sure the user has a valid login with the instance and remove user name and password while keeping Integrated Security on the connection string.
To use SQL Server Authentication, remove Integrated Security and keep the user name and password on the connection string.
